# How to do Unpivot of columns to rows in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  sample  data which I need to convert  from columns  to rows.

Input Data :

```
NAME   CLOTH SHOES  PHONE
MOHAN  YES   YES    YES
MAHESH YES   NO     NO
```

Output :

```
CATEGORY   MOHAN  MAHESH 
CLOTH      YES   YES
SHOES      YES   NO
PHONE      YES   NO
```

I have tried Case Condition but not able to move forward. Can anyone  please suggest on this.

Note : For  5.7 and below cross join is not working

Comment: @ErgestBasha Cross Join is  not  working for MYSQL 5.7

Comment: ' Cross Join is not working for MYSQL 5.7 ' - Not so cross join has been in mysql forever - there must be some other issue in your unpublished code..

Answer (score 0):

I have imported your data to [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02b295/7).

The following query shall give you the expected output :

```
SELECT 'CLOTH' AS category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mohan' THEN cloth END) AS mohan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mahesh' THEN cloth END) AS mahesh
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHOES' AS category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mohan' THEN shoes END) AS mohan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mahesh' THEN shoes END) AS mahesh
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PHONE' AS category,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mohan' THEN phone END) AS mohan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Mahesh' THEN phone END) AS mahesh
FROM your_table;
```

It gives me output as :

```
category    mohan   mahesh
CLOTH       YES     YES
SHOES       YES     NO
PHONE       YES     No
```